# How to exit from a do while loop in Java?

Tags: java, swing, loops, do-while

simple program to output number into phone number format 
I cant seem to exit the loop I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I thought 
!PhoneNumber.equals("999"); would exit the loop when the user inputs 999 but it isn't working. Can anyone help me here's my code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PhoneNumberFormat 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      String PhoneNumber;
      int numLength= 10;

      do
      {

          PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                 "Enter your 10 digit phone number or enter 999 to quit");
          while(PhoneNumber.length() != numLength)
          {
              PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                  "Error: You Entered " + PhoneNumber.length() + " digits\nPlease"
                      + " Enter a 10 digit Phone number");    
          }

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder (PhoneNumber);
            str.insert(0, '(');
            str.insert(4, ')');
            str.insert(5,' ');
            str.insert(9, '-');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your telephone number is " +str.toString());

      }while(!PhoneNumber.equals("999"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Looks to me that entering 999 will mean the code never exits the while loop.

Comment: There are potential NPE if you just left the dialog empty.

Comment: What I understand is that in first statement you are asking for 999 to quit. and then in next code you are matching if the user hasnot enter the >10 digits. You have to check also that the if user has enter 3 digits and that 3 digits is 999 then exit the loop. I believe this is what is going to work

Comment: @StackFlowed agree about potential NPE but, the NPE is only thrown if you press **Cancel** or **Close** the input dialogue box. If you press OK without providing an input, it won't be null but a string of length 0 (empty string).

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to exist when the 999 you need to add an if condition to watch for it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String PhoneNumber;
    int numLength = 10;

    do {
        PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter your 10 digit phone number or enter 999 to quit");

        // add this condition to exit the loop, as well protect against NPE
        if (PhoneNumber == null || PhoneNumber.equals("999")) {
            break;
        }

        while (PhoneNumber.length() != numLength) {
            PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Error: You Entered " + PhoneNumber.length()
                            + " digits\nPlease"
                            + " Enter a 10 digit Phone number");

            //protect against NPE
            if(PhoneNumber == null) 
               PhoneNumber = "";
        }

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(PhoneNumber);
        str.insert(0, '(');
        str.insert(4, ')');
        str.insert(5, ' ');
        str.insert(9, '-');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your telephone number is "
                + str.toString());

    } while (!PhoneNumber.equals("999"));

}
```

Comment: He wants to exist the loop and it does? Is there some other problem too?

Comment: @brso05 it won't because he forces the input to be 10 characters long.

Comment: @mibac what if he puts the `if` before the `while loop` that forces the 10 digits?

Comment: @mibac according to his question/specifications this is actually the more correct answer...

Answer (score 4):

You are forcing the number to be 10 digits, so what do you expect?  It will never be equal to the three-digit "999".

Maybe you meant to do:

```
while(!PhoneNumber.startsWith("999"));
```

Comment: @azurefrog He doesn't modify the `PhoneNumber` variable itself actually

Comment: @JamesB it's fine to change the `do while` did you try the code?

Comment: @JamesB this is a correct answer 1 of many. You shouldn't downvote correct answers. Try the code and see if it works...

Comment: @JamesB that cheers was for the compliment, messed up the reference, the comments were coming so fast maybe that's why.

Comment: @Raf no problems, nice to give credit where it is due.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use 999 as an input option to exit, allow the user to enter 999 as a valid input in the first place.

```
  int numLength= 10;
  do
  {

      PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
             "Enter your 10 digit phone number or enter 999 to quit");
      while(PhoneNumber.length() != numLength)
      {
          PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
              "Error: You Entered " + PhoneNumber.length() + " digits\nPlease"
                  + " Enter a 10 digit Phone number");    
      }
```

Here, you refuse to consider the input if its length is anything but 10.

Answer (score 2):

Code with fixing potential NPE and solving your problem should look like:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PhoneNumberFormat 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      String PhoneNumber;
      int numLength= 10;

      do
      {

          PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                 "Enter your 10 digit phone number or enter 999 to quit");
          while(PhoneNumber!=null && PhoneNumber.length() != numLength)
          {
              PhoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                  "Error: You Entered " + PhoneNumber.length() + " digits\nPlease"
                      + " Enter a 10 digit Phone number");    
          }

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder (PhoneNumber);
            str.insert(0, '(');
            str.insert(4, ')');
            str.insert(5,' ');
            str.insert(9, '-');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your telephone number is " +str.toString());

      } while(!PhoneNumber.substring(0,3).equals("999"));

    }
}
```

Fixes are on lines

```
while(PhoneNumber!=null && PhoneNumber.length() != numLength)
```

and

```
while(!PhoneNumber.substring(0,3).equals("999"));
```